# foreach loop populate array for call_user_func_array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using a `foreach` loop to populate an `array` with parameter types and parameter values before it inserts into the database. Everything works fine and posts to the db, but I can't figure out why it sends both values as the same when they are added (as a reference) to the `array`. I have tired calling `unset();` but it doesn't do the trick.

```
function insertUsers($db, $sql, $vals){
     $stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
     $types='';
     $types= $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($vals));
     $inputArray [] = &$types;

     foreach($vals as $key=>$value){
         $inputArray[]= &$value;
         unset($key);
     }
     print_r($inputArray);

     call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $inputArray);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
 }
```

The result ends being:

```
Array
(
  [0] => ss
  [1] => tyuty (note this value changes to the last value)
  [2] => tyuty 
)
```

Comment: If you want to use references to pass the result to wherever you call the function from, you need to use `&` on every step. I.e. `insertUsers($db, $sql, &$vals)`, `foreach($vals as $key=>&$value)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `&` from there inside `foreach()`;-

```
foreach($vals as $key=>&$value){ // put & here
  $inputArray[]= $value; // remove & from here and unset() not needed actually
}
```

***And Add*** `&` inside function argument too:-

```
function insertUsers($db, $sql, &$vals){
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to avoid using `call_user_func_array()` for exactly this reason. Since PHP 5.6 we have a [splat operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (`...`) that helps you avoid all this hassle.

Simply unpack the array directly in the call to `bind_param()`.

```
function insertUsers($db, $sql, $vals){
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($vals)), ...$vals);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```